# Java wildcard versus Object in API

Tags: java, generics

I have an existing Java API method:

```
public foo(Collection<Object> collection) {... }
```

Items are read from the collection param, but it is never updated. I want to change the method to:

```
public foo(Collection<?> collection) {... }
```

Is this change guaranteed to be transparent, safe, and without side effects for users?

Note: Not sure if it is important, but the API also contains this method:

```
public foo(Object object) { ... }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having the parameter as `Collection<?>` *allows* the users to pass whatever `Collection` they want to the method, because `Collection<?>` is actually a super type of all types of collections.

In the meantime, `Collection<Object>` will be compatible with `Collection<Object>` values only, but not with `Collection<String>`, `Collection<Integer>`, etc., which makes the difference between the two approaches.

To summarize, with applying this change you actually break the method's initial intent, which is to work with collections of `Object`s only.

The `foo(Object object)` method is just a method overload for the `foo(Collection<Object> object)` method and nothing more.

Comment: Thanks! This is the answer I needed. I mentioned foo(Object) because users were unintentionally invoking this method when trying to pass Collection<String>, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It has the "side effect" that the original method could not be called on `Collection<String>` while the second will allow using `Collection<String>` as the call parameter.